# Python: MySQL connection is open, but can't create cursor

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to open a cursor to a MySQL-DB. But I'm getting this error:

```python
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Here is a small sourcecode:

```python
class Sample:
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = None
    self.value = self.setValue()

  def connect(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)
    #cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("SELECT ...")
    #value = str(cursor.fetchone()[0])
    #raise Exception(value)
    #cursor.close() <- here everything is working fine

  def setValue(self):
    if (self.conn == None):
    self.connect()      
    #raise Exception(self.conn.open)
    cursor = self.conn.cursor() # ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
    ...
```

If I use the exception I get a 1 ... connection is open.

And if I do the cursor creation and the SQL statement in the 'connect' function everything is working well.

The strange this is, everything looks correct and for some other connections with the same functions everything is working well, too. I don't know how to solve this error. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing out some important piece of code? Isn't it possible it's error on another line, or you put it accidentally into different object?

Comment: @Vyktor: I added some more code.

Comment: @eandersson no, you're wrong. You should **always** close cursor manually. You'll get memory leaks otherwise.

Comment: Can you show us how you call the functions `connect` and `setValue`?

Comment: @Vyktor My bad, didn't think that one through properly.

Comment: What does `print(self.conn)` say right before the problematic line?

Comment: @Vyktor: It gives an error: 'Connection' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the statement that checks if the connection is open to both check if conn is none as well as if the connection is open. And because you always execute the `setValue` function I would recommend that you call the connect inside the`__init__` function.

```python
class Sample:
  conn = None

  def __init__(self):
    self.connect()
    self.value = self.setValue()
    self.close()

  def connect(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)

  def close(self):
    if self.conn:
       self.conn.close()

  def setValue(self):
    if not self.conn and not self.conn.open:
       self.connect()
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

Also, remember that with the Python MySQL Connector you need to call commit after you execute a insert or update statement.

```python
cur =  self.conn.cursor()
cur.execute("...")
self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I only connect once.

Comment: If there is a different issue it is not showing in the code you attached. Consider showing us more of your code.

Comment: It's sadly not working, because one line above the connection is open.

Comment: @Joko if the above code is not working the issue is probably something not shown in the code above.

Comment: I wondering, why if I run the code in the comments in the 'connect' function everything works fine.

Comment: Most likely you did something wrong with the if (self.connect == None). The code in your question is missing white spaces (indent). And because it didn't work and the `__init__` set it to None, it stayed as None.

Comment: The simplest solution is to simply start the connection in your __init__ function.