# I am trying to open a cursor. Its not working despite there being a conncection with mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want to execute mysql query using cursor, but I am unable to do so. The error shows :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

There are total of 3 cursors in my code( I couldnt get it working with just 1) and all of them are connected ( I checked this by debugging )

I have already gone through this thread and it doesnt work [Python: MySQL connection is open, but can't create cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195118/python-mysql-connection-is-open-but-cant-create-cursor)

from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
import mysql.connector

```
#from mysql.connector import error
class HTML2PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass


conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='swd',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='param2000')
conn1 = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='swd',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='param2000')
conn2 = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='swd',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='param2000')
#all 3 are successfully connected
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from 14batch")
row=cursor.fetchone()
#cursor works perfectly

html='''blah blah blah'''
cursor1=conn1.connect()
cursor1.execute("SELECT * from med_ins_14batch where uid='row[0]'")
#it throws me an error in the above line
row1 = cursor1.fetchone()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the differences in your code.

At first, `cursor` is being created using a cursor.
At second, `cursor1` is not being created the same way.

Change the failing set of lines to:

```
html='''blah blah blah'''
cursor1=conn1.cursor()
cursor1.execute("SELECT * from med_ins_14batch where uid='row[0]'")
#this should work now
row1 = cursor1.fetchone()
```